# Swift compiler issue : Compiler doesn't compile long parameters array for Alamofire post request

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

It seems a bug or any other issue that compiler fails to compile large parameters array and doesn't proceed building.Your help will be appreciated. here is my code :

```
    let company_id = self.globals.company_id!
    let user_id = self.globals.user_id!
    var f_no = ""
    if let filght_no = self.tfFlightNo.text {
        f_no  = "assets/uploads/images/img_\(filght_no).png"
    }
    let urlString = "...."
    let param : [String : Any] = ["flight_remarks" : self.txtRemarks.text!, "tocountry":self.country2DropDownView.text!, "fromcountry" : self.Country1DropDownView.text!, "statusdate":self.tfStatusDate.text!, "flightstatus" : self.statusDropDownView.text!, "flightairline" : self.tfAirline.text! , "flightfrom" : self.AirportFromDropDownView.text!,"flightto" : self.AirportToDropDownView.text!, "flighttype" : self.TypeDropDownView.text!,"flightdatefrom" : self.tfDateFrom.text!,"flightdateto":self.tfDateTo.text!, "timeto" : self.tfTimeTo.text!,"flightcnfcode" : self.tfFlightConfriationCode.text!, "timefrom" : self.tfTimeFrom.text!,"pax":self.total_pax,"flightcnfremarks" : self.txtViewFlightConfirmationRemarks.text!,"flightcnfdate" : self.tfFlightConfirmationDate.text!,"flightno" : self.tfFlightNo.text!,"trip_id" : self.trip_id, "guest" : self.guest_id,"flight_ticket_pdf" : f_no,"imagefile" : f_no]
    Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: param ,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON {
        response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            print(response)

            break
        case .failure(let error):

            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the compiling error you are getting ?

Comment: Actually, there is no error, compiler stucks during project building.

Comment: If i comment these lines, compiler doesn't stuck and builds project successfully.

Comment: @Ibrar where is your `request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way

```
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

let values : [String : Any] = ["flight_remarks" : self.txtRemarks.text!, "tocountry":self.country2DropDownView.text!, "fromcountry" : self.Country1DropDownView.text!, "statusdate":self.tfStatusDate.text!, "flightstatus" : self.statusDropDownView.text!, "flightairline" : self.tfAirline.text! , "flightfrom" : self.AirportFromDropDownView.text!,"flightto" : self.AirportToDropDownView.text!, "flighttype" : self.TypeDropDownView.text!,"flightdatefrom" : self.tfDateFrom.text!,"flightdateto":self.tfDateTo.text!, "timeto" : self.tfTimeTo.text!,"flightcnfcode" : self.tfFlightConfriationCode.text!, "timefrom" : self.tfTimeFrom.text!,"pax":self.total_pax,"flightcnfremarks" : self.txtViewFlightConfirmationRemarks.text!,"flightcnfdate" : self.tfFlightConfirmationDate.text!,"flightno" : self.tfFlightNo.text!,"trip_id" : self.trip_id, "guest" : self.guest_id,"flight_ticket_pdf" : f_no,"imagefile" : f_no]

request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: values)

Alamofire.request(request)
    .responseJSON { response in
        // do whatever you want here
        switch response.result {
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)

            if let data = response.data, let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print(responseString)
            }
        case .success(let responseObject):
            print(responseObject)
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Nazmul Hasan